# user already logged in but it try to open login link then how to redirect specified path in laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication

```
http://localhost/admin/login
```

I have logged in then I am redirecting to

```
localhost/admin/
```

Now I am open `localhost/admin/login`
then I want to redirect on

```
localhost/admin/dashboard not on 

localhost/admin/
```

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put it in your auth controller.

protected $redirectTo = '/admin/dashboard';

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this,
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if the user is logged :

```
if (Auth::check()) {
    return Redirect::to('localhost/admin/');
}else{
    log-in part
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to simply check for the that particular user is logged into system using below code -

```
if (Auth::check()) {
    return Redirect::to('admin/dashboard');
}else{
    return Redirect::to('login/admin');
}
```

If user is logged in then redirect to dashboard of admin & 
If user isn't logged in then redirect to login blade of the project.

Comment: Thank you, So much